# PlugNPlay sdk framework can't be imported in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: swift3

Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1 For PlugNPlay SDK. Please provide a new release for PlugNPlay SDK with swift 3.1 support.
it is working fine in Simulator but it showing an error if you run in device **Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1**

My Xcode version is 8.3.2
iPhone Device version is 10.3.1 and 10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some setting of your project so you can easily import PlugNPlay sdk framework. I am attaching screenshot here.

[image: You Have to change in Pod File.]

[image: You have to change build setting of application. in this you have to set framework search path.]

Comment: Hi Brijesh, Thanks for your valuable response.I set info file according to you but still same error showing.

Comment: Ok. When you have some time then contact me. I'll try to resolve your problem.
Skype: prince.bnr